# MatPlotLib text position strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a function to display scatter plots:

```python
def critics_and_users_score_corr_with_total_sales(_df, platform):
    critic_score_not_na = df['critic_score'].notna() & (df['platform'] == platform)
    total_sales_for_critic_score = df[critic_score_not_na]['total_sales']
    critic_score = df[critic_score_not_na]['critic_score']

    user_score_not_na = df['user_score'].notna() & (df['platform'] == platform)
    total_sales_for_user_score = df[user_score_not_na]['total_sales']
    user_score = df[user_score_not_na]['user_score']

    info_bbox_props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', alpha=0.2)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.set_xlim(0,25)
    ax1.set_title('{} Critics score & Total sales correlation'.format(platform))
    ax1.set_xlabel('Total sales')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Critics score')
    ax1.scatter(total_sales_for_critic_score, critic_score, s = 10)

    ax1.text(0.345, 0.88, 'Corelation: {:.2f}'.format(total_sales_for_critic_score.corr(critic_score)), 
             transform=ax.transAxes, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right', bbox=info_bbox_props)

    ax2.grid(True)
    ax2.set_xlim(0,25)
    ax2.set_title('{} Users score & Total sales correlation'.format(platform))
    ax2.set_xlabel('Total sales')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Users score')
    ax2.scatter(total_sales_for_user_score, user_score, s = 10)
    ax2.text(0.892, 0.88, 'Corelation: {:.2f}'.format(total_sales_for_user_score.corr(user_score)), 
             transform=ax.transAxes, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right', bbox=info_bbox_props)

    plt.show()
```

I call this function further in code:

```
critics_and_users_score_corr_with_total_sales(df, top_platforms.index[0])
```

And here is the result:
[image]
As we can see, text fields are placed outside the plots.

But if I run this cell by `Shift+Enter` the second and subsequent time - text the fields are placed in other location:
[image]

If I restart the Kernel and run all cells, the text fields are placed outside the plot again.

What kind of magic is this?

Comment: The magic might happen in the 30 cells of your notebook, which you don't show here. See [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was in following lines:

```
ax1.text(0.345, 0.88, 'Corelation: {:.2f}'.format(total_sales_for_critic_score.corr(critic_score)), 
         transform=ax.transAxes, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right', bbox=info_bbox_props)
```

My ax has a `ax1` name, but I send to parameters `transform=ax.transAxes`. Obviously, `ax` was declared in other place.

My bad.